# Matching on a system.string value

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to invoke a command and getting the result as a system.string, i need to match on a part of the result as a check point to continue with my script.

For Example i have add the result in a variable called $upgradecomm, If i try to print it the below is what i get:

```
C:\> $upgradecomm


Host       : HQ-ESXi-Edge-01a.nsx.gss
Output     : {Update Result,    Message: The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.,    Reboot Required: true,    VIBs 
             Installed: VMware_bootbank.........
```

"The above output still have more but i am not adding them to this post."

What i need is to match on the part that say (The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.) in the message part.

If i print only the output i would get the below:

```
C:\> $upgradecomm.Output
Update Result
   Message: The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.
   Reboot Required: true
   VIBs Installed: VMware_bootbank.....................
```

"The above output still have more but i am not adding them to this post."

I am not able to get to what i need here as i said i need to make a check if i got the following from the result (The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.) so that i can continue my script and if i did not get i will print an error.

Any Idea will be appreciated.

Comment: `.Output -like '*completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted*'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the rest of the text says, a simple `-like` should suffice.

```
$success = "*The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.*"
if($upgradecomm.Output -like $success){
#success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Output`-property is an array of strings. You can use ex. `-match` to search the array for strings matching your keywords. If it returns any, it was a match.

```
#Creating sampleobject
$o = "Update Result",
"   Message: The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective.",
"   Reboot Required: true",
"   VIBs Installed: VMware_bootbank....................."

$upgradecomm = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Host = "Server1"
    Output = $o
}

#Verify that sampleobject is correct
$upgradecomm | Format-List *
#Output

Host   : Server1
Output : {Update Result,    Message: The update completed successfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effe
         ctive.,    Reboot Required: true,    VIBs Installed: VMware_bootbank.....................}

#Check if successfull and rebooted are in the message-string in output
if($upgradecomm.Output -match 'Message: .*?successfull.*?rebooted') { "Do something" }
#Output
Do something
```